# Changing text of a span moves parent element left

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I apologize if someone can immediately direct me to the right place, but I'm unsure what to even search for this particular problem. It seems to be a Chrome-specific bug, but I'm unsure how to fix it.

What's happening is that when I replace the text in a span, it's moving a (grand)parent anchor to the left. (see fiddle for demo : http://jsfiddle.net/Sj3Gj/2/) I've simplified the HTML, but for various reasons, this is the structure/CSS I need. If you put float: left on the anchor element, it works fine, but I have this structure in a larger  and this additional float breaks the positioning of the larger structure.

I'm at a complete loss here. If you look at the fiddle in chrome, the anchor floats left, but in Firefox/IE, it's fine. Any ideas?

Here's my code:

```
<a class="trigger">
    <div></div>
    <span>Some text</span>
</a>

a.trigger {
    width: 337px;
    height: 16px;
    padding: 2px 20px 2px 5px;
    margin-top: 3px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
a.trigger, a.trigger:link, a.trigger:visited {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-top-color: #BFD6F1;
    border-left-color: #BFD6F1;
    border-bottom-color: #9EBCE1;
    border-right-color: #9EBCE1;
    padding: 2px 18px 2px 7px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

div{
    background-image: url('http://placekitten.com/200/300');
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}
a.trigger span {
    margin-left: 10px;
}
a.trigger, a.trigger:link, a.trigger:visited {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is sbecause you are floating the div to the left. remove the float, it is not needed as you have already declared `inline-block`

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/Sj3Gj/5/

```
div{
    background-image: url('http://placekitten.com/200/300');
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: I guess I have to give up on this issue. For some reason, when I remove the float, it bumps the text down to the next line (within my actual project), but I'm unable to recreate it in the fiddle. So...apparently I'm making stuff up. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: You have an anchor tag wrapped a div tag. This only came into effect in `html5`. Before that, you couldn't wrap an anchor around a div. Ensure you have set the correct `doctype` within your `html` document, otherwise it can cause different browsers to behave strangely.